# Azure Websites A Record 404

Tags: azure, dns, alias, azure-web-app-service, cname

I have configured my dns for yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk from 123-reg.co.uk as follows:

awverify    CNAME    awverify.yis.azure
www         CNAME    yis.azurewebsites.net
@           A        65.52.128.33

If I do an "nslookup yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk" then it resolves to the correct ip address (65.52.128.33)

The Azure portal seemed to accept that the CNAME was correctly configured since it allowed me to make an entry for the naked domain name "yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk" as can be seen in the following screen grab.

[image]

My problem is that if I direct my browser to the naked domain "yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk" then I get a 404. If I prefix with www then it works ok. Can anyone please explain why my A record is not working?

Comment: is that CNAME line correct?  it appears to be truncated in spots.

Comment: What was your final solution?

Comment: @RobBowman Did you manage to get this working without using the @ for the CName, I don't want to do this because it would override my mail DNS bindings.  I'm also using azure and 123-reg.  I have the www binding but not the naked binding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do an NS lookup on yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk

```
C:\>nslookup
> set querytype=soa
> yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
Server:  utdc.xxxxxx.com
Address:  172.16.1.2

Non-authoritative answer:
yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
        primary name server = ns.123-reg.co.uk
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
        serial  = 2013062302
        refresh = 86400 (1 day)
        retry   = 0 (0 secs)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 86400 (1 day)

ns.123-reg.co.uk        internet address = 212.67.202.2
```

Then for www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk:

```
C:\>nslookup
Default Server:  utdc.xxxxxx.com
Address:  172.16.1.2

> www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
Server:  utdc.xxxxxx.com
Address:  172.16.1.2

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    waws-prod-am2-001.cloudapp.net
Address:  65.52.128.33
Aliases:  www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
          yis.azurewebsites.net
          waws-prod-am2-001.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net

> set querytype=soa
> www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk
Server:  utdc.xxxxxx.com
Address:  172.16.1.2

Non-authoritative answer:
www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk        canonical name = yis.azurewebsites.net
yis.azurewebsites.net   canonical name = waws-prod-am2-001.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net
waws-prod-am2-001.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net canonical name = waws-prod-am2-001.cloudapp.net
>
```

This would seem to suggest that the two sites are not set up the same.  WWW is set up as an alias (cname) through azure, where the other appears to be an A record through 123-reg.

Still, they are both going through the same IP address.  I assume you are not doing anything in your app to restrict domain names?

Of all the domains:

```
yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk - Fails 404
www.yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk - Works
yis.azurewebsites.net - Works
waws-prod-am2-001.vip.azurewebsites.windows.net - Fails 404
waws-prod-am2-001.cloudapp.net - Fails 404
65.52.128.33 - Fails 404
```

All pointing to the same IP address.

The crux seems to lie in [making an alias](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns-web-site/#bkmk_configurecname) of yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk as well as the www.  You need a CNAME reference for both of them pointing to yis.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response - I've been on holiday! The problem was solved when I added another CNAME record - this time for "@" pointing to yis.azurewebsites.net. After doing that I was able to add an entry for the naked domain "yorkshireimagescanning.co.uk" in the amazon portal.